# ruby pass argument into inner method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to programming and I'm doing rails. Here I have a ruby question.

I have a method counterpart which take message and conversation as argument

```
    def counterpart(message, conversation)
        if  message.author_id == conversation.sender_id
          counterpart_id = conversation.receiver_id
        else
          counterpart_id = conversation.sender_id
        end
    end
```

and in below method create_notification, I want to call counterpart method within to get variable counterpart_id. But how can I pass the argument message and conversation into counterpart here?

```
    def create_notification(message, conversation)
        counterpart(message, conversation)
        notification = message.create_notification(
                  notifier_id: message.author_id,
                  receiver_id: counterpart_id,
                  content: "#{message.author.name} sent you a message",
                  title: "message")
    end
```

thanks

Comment: you are passing the arguments `message` and `conversation` into `counterpart` - maybe you've made a typo, but as written, I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: @dax But it didn't save the new notification into my db. I don't know why...

Comment: Assuming that `Notification` has some relationship to message, try calling the create method with a `!` - that will throw an error if something goes wrong: `message.create_notification!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know enough about your models. So, as far as I know, the best way to make your code works is move to

```
def counterpart(message, conversation)
  message.author_id == conversation.sender_id ? conversation.receiver_id : conversation.sender_id
end

def create_notification(message, conversation)
  message.create_notification(notifier_id: message.author_id,
      receiver_id: counterpart(message, conversation),
      content: "#{message.author.name} sent you a message",
      title: "message")
end
```